langchain_community.utilities.sql_database.SQLDatabase adds a "\" character before each "_" character in PostgreSQL DB queries
I am using langchain_community.utilities.sql_database.SQLDatabase for RAG against a PostgreSQL database.
I am noticing that some queries being generated as a result of RAG contain the character \ preceding each _ character in the table name and table field name.
This "escaping" changes the names of the table and field objects hereby making the SQL query string invalid.
For example the query below is generated by RAG.
SELECT friend\_id FROM friend\_node WHERE nickname = 'Bob';

Generates the error below.
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: SELECT friend\_id FROM friend\_node WHERE nickname = 'Bob'; ^

While the valid query string should be
SELECT friend_id FROM friend_node WHERE nickname = 'Bob';

Is there a mechanism (or hints) that disable this "feature"?

Basically, is there a way I can modify the LLM generated query before it is executed?
